# Windows XP image sysprepped in VirtualBox fails to boot on bare metal

Tags: windows-xp, virtualbox, sysprep

(1) I created a VirtualBox virtual machine and installed then customized a Windows XP SP3 reference system in it.

(2) I ran sysprep to reseal the system for deployment. By restarting the virtual machine directly I saw that sysprep ran as configured and the system was correctly deployed.

(3) However, after using Symantec Ghost 11.5 to make an image of the system and deploying it to a real physical machine, the Windows XP sysprepped system fails to boot. Specifically, the system keep restarting even before the Windows logo shows up.

Is there some difference between a VirtualBox virtual machine and a real bare metal system that I need to account for? And is there a way to salvage my current virtual reference system without having to remake it from scratch on bare metal?

Thanks!!

Comment: Obligatory: [*Why are you still running Windows XP*](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/end-support-help)? [Professionals](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/4111/what-is-a-professional-capacity) generally don't deploy out-of-support software...

Comment: Agreed, windows xp should be being scrubbed from your environment and your hours should be spent on migration considerations, not on deploying an aging and soon to be extremely vulnerable OS.

Comment: I couldn't agree with you more. Unfortunately my organisation's management is mired in red tape and bureaucracy (who don't know anything about IT) that is forcing us to continue to make and deploy new Windows XP images despite our objections..... I wish I know how to change this!! Thanks for your help, though!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is likely down to ATA / AHCI support. On the baremetal computer you're attempting to install, open the bios settings dialog and check to see if you can reconfigure SATA to be ATA instead of AHCI.

XP did not ship with AHCI support, nearly every modern computer comes with this feature and the option is generally enabled.